# How to use Firebase in all documents?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-cloud-firestore

My firebase is setup and initialized in my index.html, but then I can only use it there. Is there any way to use it on all documents?

It is set up in my index page, and then I use the data base and JQuery on a separate JS file to manipulate things also in that index page. I am doing similar things on another HTML page but when I call a function, it doesn't do anything/can't get the data. I thought I should initialize the database on that page too (within script tags of course, just copy/paste the code to initialize), and that also doesn't do anything. I also tried initializing it within the JS code as well, which seems to be the most intuitive thing to do, and that doesn't work either.

I initialize the database with the following:

```
var firebaseConfig = {...}
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
var db = firebase.firestore();
```

Then just below, I can call a function in the JS and it uses the database information. But when I call a function in another HTML doc, it won't use the database.

I have initialized it in the JS file itself before, and that got me what I wanted but I can't do it again for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Once you navigate from one page to the next, you browser pretty much forgets anything from the previous page. This means that you will need to include Firebase into any page where you use it.

Firebase is often used in so-called single-page applications, which are implemented as a single real page, but emulate many application screens within that page. That way they only have to include/load Firebase once, but can still show multiple screens to the user. If you're interested in this approach, I recommend looking into some common single-page application frameworks, such as Angular, React, and Vue.